# How to replace threads in Django to Celery worker

Tags: python, django, celery

I know it's not the best practice to use threads in django project but I have a project that is using threads:
`threading.Thread(target=save_data, args=(dp, conv_handler)).start()`

I want to replace this code to celery - to run worker with function
`save_data(dispatcher, conversion)`

Inside save_data I have infinite loop and in this loop I save states of `dispatcher` and `conversation` to file on disk with pickle.

I want to know may I use celery for such work?
Does the worker can see changes of state in dispatcher and conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't like long running tasks in Celery. Normally you will have a maximum task time and if your task takes too much time it can time out. The best tasks for celery are quick and stateless tasks.

Notice that Celery params are serialized when you launch a task and it's tricky passing a python object as a task argument (not recommended).

I would need more info about the problem you are trying to solve but if dispatcher & conversion are django objects I would do something like:

```
def save_data(dispatcher_id, conversion_id):
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.objects.get(id=dispatcher_id)
    conversion = Conversion.objects.get(id_conversion_id)
```

And you should avoid that infinite loop in a celery task. You can workaround the infinite loop by calling this save_task periodically but I encourage you to find a solution that matches better with Celery (try to be stateless, quick tasks).

Comment: No, it's not database objects. dispatcher and conversation are python objects. I want to persist their states and I don't really know how to do it better. I shared code here https://pastebin.com/JWpTr7KB

Comment: Then I don't recommend you using Celery for this task. You should try with a different approach.
You could use celery to write data to a disk file but you will still need an event loop that listens indefinitely the incoming events